# Toggle a mixin in CesiumJS

Tags: cesiumjs

in order to have a better overview over the performance of a Cesium project, I would like to be able to toggle Cesium's inspector panel.
Now I can add the Mixin with the following code

```
viewer.extend(Cesium.viewerCesiumInspectorMixin);
```

but how can I remove it from the Viewer? 
Cannot seem to find a method in the viewer documentation. 
Thanks!

Comment: I think the Inspector is meant for debugging purposes only...and not for running on the production system. But I would be handy nevertheless.